# Error in linux script

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I have written the below script to check whether my server running fine or not.But it is not properly working.It always showing Not runing even if it is running fine.Also the telnet in the script is not running working properly .Can any one help?

```
#!/bin/sh
export smtp=smtprelay.intra.xxx.com:25
Connect_redmine(){
telnet redmine.intra.xxx.com 443 <<EOF
exit 1;
EOF
}

Connect_redmine>/home/ssx00001/log_connect.txt
grep "Connected" /home/ssx00001/log_connect.txt
status=$?
if [ $status == 0 ]; then
echo `date`  "Redmine PROD server is running fine"|mailx -r Redmine@xxx -s "Redmine PROD server is running" 777.p@xxx.com
else
echo "Redmine PROD server  is not Running"|mailx -r redmine@xxx.com -s "Redmine PROD server is not running" 777.p@xxx.com
fi
```

Comment: Please show contents of `/home/ssx00001/log_connect.txt`.

Comment: It is empty .The script is not able to append the telnet result to the File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of questions first:

1] What does redmine do?  Is it just a HTTPS server?

2] If [1] is true, can you do a wget of the index page, and use the result of that? It should be a lot easier to parse.

3] Telnetting into a HTTPS server, as far as I know, won't work, because it's not doing any of the handshaking that would be necessary for an SSL connection (which needs to occur before any content will be sent).

Using wget, you can do something like this:

wget https://redmine.intra.xxx.com/index.html

if [[-f "index.html" ] && [ -s "index.html" ]]

then

# The service is live

else

# Something is wrong

fi

Comment: Redmine is a bugtracking tool and it is onfigured in HTTPS. The above getting error is bcoz of port number 443 is not working in telnet.But I dont know hw to resolve it

Comment: See number [3] for the reason that telnet isn't working.  Can you do nr 2?

Comment: @roelfos: It (telnet) was working fine earlier.But now it is not working.

Comment: Can you post a log?  I was wrong earlier - telnet will connect, it just won't go any further like you could with a normal HTTP server.

Comment: I still think this is a very kludgy approach, and would rather attempt to just retrieve the index.html file, or any artefact on the first page using curl or wget.  You can then just check for existence and non-zero filesize, and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ,Im using a linux server,The above code will work only in windows right?